# Is it possible to specify COM enum field name using an attribute?

Tags: c#, attributes, enums, com-interop

I am replacing (part of) a Delphi COM library with a .net assembly.  I have moved a number of the COM interfaces and enums to the .net assembly.  Everything is fine except that the enums are exported to the type library using a {enum_type_name}_{enum_value_name} naming convention.

Example

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("318f9e87-444c-11d5-aed1-00105a758da4")]
public enum KeyIDEnum
{
    keLeft = 0,
    keCentre = 1,
    keRight = 2
}
```

Becomes

```
[
  uuid(318F9E87-444C-11D5-AED1-00105A758DA4),
  version(1.0)
]
typedef enum tagKeyIDEnum
{
  KeyIDEnum_keLeft = 0,
  KeyIDEnum_keCentre = 1,
  KeyIDEnum_keRight = 2
} KeyIDEnum;
```

I would like to know if there is any way to override this default behavior and specify the enum value names, possibly using an attribute.  Something like:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("318f9e87-444c-11d5-aed1-00105a758da4")]
public enum KeyIDEnum
{
    [Name("keLeft")]
    keLeft = 0,
    [Name("keCentre")]
    keCentre = 1,
    [Name("keRight")]
    keRight = 2
}
```

I'm almost certain there is a way to do this I just need to know which attribute class to use.

Comment: Nope, not an option.  Copy paste it into a .idl file and compile with midl.exe if you want to control the names.  Or just use the type library you already have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, I believe it can be done but it is not easy. I am almost certain an attribute will not do the trick as the MSDN page on exported [type conversion talks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46f8ac6z.aspx#cpcontlbexptypeconversionanchor4) about the prefixing but does not mention related attributes (whereas other parts of the page do). The listing of classes in [System.Runtime.InteropServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.aspx) (where COM-related attributes live) also does not have any attributes that appear promising.

Finally, a [blog post](http://blogs.artinsoft.net/mrojas/archive/2010/05/17/interop-remove-prefix-from-c-enums-for-com.aspx) by Mauricio Rojas describes how to do it by modifying the IDL but it looks ugly. (A few other blogs have similar descriptions.)